# Magento 1: Cannot save Dataflow profiles

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

When I try and edit and existing dataflow profile, or add a new one, I get a blank page /`admin/system_convert_gui/save/key/98db.../continue/true/` displaying only "**NULL**" and nothing is saved.

I've checked for and errant die() in the process, but haven't found anything.  Not sure where to begin looking further.

Comment: Anything in your `system.log`, `exception.log` or general php error log?